# Upload Jenkins build file .war to Nexus Repository remotely

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, war, nexus

I have Jenkins setup with Maven as a build tool. Java project is pulled from SVN and it is built using Maven (all inside Jenkins). Once the project is built I get `project.war` package file which I need to be uploaded to Nexus Repository.

Whats the simplest way to do that?

I tried tweaking/modifying my existing `settings.xml` and `pom.xml`, but no luck.  Nothing is happening.

I want the `.war` file to be uploaded to Nexus Repository which I configured on other box.

Comment: Example how to do this: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/02/27/setup-local-nexus-repository-and-deploy-war-file-from-maven/

Comment: Have you tried `mvn deploy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Nexus Maven Plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html) for your purpose. And in your Jenkins script, just run:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

As it is described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried mvn deploy, mvn clean deploy but neither work.. "mvn" dont work (May be I need to set environment variable or something.. help me ! with that too ! :))

Somehow it worked fine now. I am using the Goal as : **clean deploy** it worked for me. Also, when I used below in pom.xml file :-

    
    release and then snapshot

It didn't worked.

However, I have created new repo in nexus and provided its path. It worked fine. Jenkins was able to upload my .war file to Nexus repo.

Now Next I have to do is,

As many build my jenkin produces and push to Nexus. Nexus should version it for me.. Any idea would be really appreciated